# Upload file via FTP - Server returned error (550) File is unavailable, cannot find file

Tags: c#, vb.net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to upload a file via FTP from my local computer to an FTP server, which is also on my local computer at the moment. I've got this sub I'm calling:

```
    Public Sub UploadFTPFile(ByVal ftpservername, ByVal fullfilepath, ByVal filename, ByVal username, ByVal password)

    Dim clsRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = _
    DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://" & ftpservername & "/" & filename), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
    clsRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
    clsRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

    clsRequest.KeepAlive = False

    ' read in file...
    Dim bFile() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullfilepath)

    ' upload file...
    Dim clsStream As System.IO.Stream = _
        clsRequest.GetRequestStream()
    clsStream.Write(bFile, 0, bFile.Length)
    clsStream.Close()
    clsStream.Dispose()
End Sub
```

When calling the sub, I do it like this:

```
UploadFTPFile("192.168.1.3/Temp", selectedSoundFileLong, OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName, "", "")
```

In other words, in the Sub, this string:

```
DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://" & ftpservername & "/" & filename), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
```

, creates the following:

```
    DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.1.3/Temp/test.mp3"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
```

And at this line in the sub:

```
        Dim clsStream As System.IO.Stream = _
        clsRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

This error occurs:

```
The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable
```

What could be the cause of this?
I'm running an FTP Server using Golder FTP Server, which is freeware. 
I think it's setup correctly because connecting to the FTP Server using the exact same string as above using Windows Explorer works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure there is no extra white space in the webRequest string?  I believe you would get this error if the string happened to be like "ftp://192.168.1.3/ Temp/test.mp3"  Also, check to make sure you have the correct privileges to write to that server.  Additionally, make sure you file is test.mp3 and not test.MP3.

Comment: I didn't have ny spaces in the filename at all. The priveleges to write to the server was the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Try flipping the [UsePassive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usepassive.aspx) property.  Control and data use [different ports in FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Connection_methods), it's possible you're getting through on the control port but getting blocked somehow on the data port.

Comment: Thanx, I tried this and it seemed to do the trick :)
Even though, it didn't work alone, I needed to set some settings on the FTP Server to be able to allow incoming traffic. Works now, thanx! :)

Comment: Btw, any idea how I can have a progressbar show the progress?

Answer (score 0):

**550 is a System.Net.FtpWebRequest connection error code.**

Also you have not constructed your FTP correctly check out my FTP class: Its pretty straight forward.

```
Public Class FTP
        '-------------------------[BroCode]--------------------------
        '----------------------------FTP-----------------------------
        Private _credentials As System.Net.NetworkCredential
        Sub New(ByVal _FTPUser As String, ByVal _FTPPass As String)
            setCredentials(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)
        End Sub
        Public Sub UploadFile(ByVal _FileName As String, ByVal _UploadPath As String)
            Dim _FileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName)
            Dim _FtpWebRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(_UploadPath)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
            _FtpWebRequest.Credentials = _credentials
            _FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive = False
            _FtpWebRequest.Timeout = 20000
            _FtpWebRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
            _FtpWebRequest.UseBinary = True
            _FtpWebRequest.ContentLength = _FileInfo.Length
            Dim buffLength As Integer = 2048
            Dim buff(buffLength - 1) As Byte
            Dim _FileStream As System.IO.FileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead()
            Try
                Dim _Stream As System.IO.Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
                Dim contentLen As Integer = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
                Do While contentLen <> 0
                    _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen)
                    contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
                Loop
                _Stream.Close()
                _Stream.Dispose()
                _FileStream.Close()
                _FileStream.Dispose()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error: ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End Sub
        Public Sub DownloadFile(ByVal _FileName As String, ByVal _ftpDownloadPath As String)
            Try
                Dim _request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(_ftpDownloadPath)
                _request.KeepAlive = False
                _request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
                _request.Credentials = _credentials
                Dim _response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = _request.GetResponse()
                Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream = _response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
                responseStream.CopyTo(fs)
                responseStream.Close()
                _response.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Download Error: ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End Sub
        Public Function GetDirectory(ByVal _ftpPath As String) As List(Of String)
            Dim ret As New List(Of String)
            Try
                Dim _request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(_ftpPath)
                _request.KeepAlive = False
                _request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
                _request.Credentials = _credentials
                Dim _response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = _request.GetResponse()
                Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream = _response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim _reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream)
                Dim FileData As String = _reader.ReadToEnd
                Dim Lines() As String = FileData.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                For Each l As String In Lines
                    ret.Add(l)
                Next
                _reader.Close()
                _response.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Directory Fetch Error: ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
            Return ret
        End Function

        Private Sub setCredentials(ByVal _FTPUser As String, ByVal _FTPPass As String)
            _credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

To initialize:

```
Dim ftp As New FORM.FTP("username", "password")

ftp.UploadFile("c:\file.jpeg", "ftp://domain/file.jpeg")

ftp.DownloadFile("c:\file.jpeg", "ftp://ftp://domain/file.jpeg")

Dim directory As List(Of String) = ftp.GetDirectory("ftp://ftp.domain.net/")
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each item As String In directory
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
```